# Idiom or phrase to describe a short-lived reward

Tags: idioms

Are there any **idioms** or **phrases** to describe **a short-lived reward**

For example, in a gang robbery incident where the robbers robbed a million, but three days later, all of them were caught with the million, which they did even spent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common expression is the extragrammatical but transparent idiom, **Easy come, easy go.**

> *easy come, easy go* [informal]
>
> said when something, especially money, is easily gotten and then
> soon spent or lost

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/easy-come-easy-go)]

> - A: I lost the fifty dollars I won at the casino really quickly.
> - B: Well, easy come, easy go.

[[LanguageCouncils.sg](https://www.languagecouncils.sg/goodenglish/resources/idioms/easy-come-easy-go)]

(The idiom is also often used of the character of someone content to live in the way implied.)

......................

Another, slightly less transparent metaphor is **Riches have wings / Money has wings.**

> Riches have wings:
>
> ... *Money can disappear easily. Money is like a bird with wings: it*
> *can fly away if you are not careful.*

[[EnglishClub](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Sayings/Quizzes/Mixed_7/Riches_have_wings_888.php#:%7E:text=This%20page%20is%20about%20the,if%20you%20are%20not%20careful.)]

The source of this metaphor / adage is the Bible:

> Proverbs 23:5 [New International Version;
> BibleHub.com](https://biblehub.com/proverbs/23-5.htm)
>
> - *Cast but a glance at riches, and they are gone, for they will surely sprout wings and fly off to the sky like an eagle.*

.................

And there are various translations of Proverbs 13:11 [[again, BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/proverbs/13-11.htm)]

> - *The more easily you get your wealth, the sooner you will lose it. The harder it is to earn, the more you will have.* [Good News
>   Translation]
> - *Wealth gained by dishonesty will be diminished, But he who gathers by labor will increase.* [New King James Version]
> - *Wealth gained hastily will dwindle, but whoever gathers little by little will increase it.* [English Standard Version]
> - *Wealth from get-rich-quick schemes quickly disappears; wealth from hard work grows over time.* [New Living Translation]

Pick whichever version best fits your purpose; preachers do.

Answer (score 1):

I offer this idiom from [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/here+today+and+gone+tomorrow!)

> **here today, (and) gone tomorrow**
>
> Said of something that is short-lived.
> *I can't believe I've already spent the money I got for my birthday.*